# How to find the extrema of a discrete function

Tags: optimization, algorithms

It's easy to find the extrema of a differentiable function. But, unfortunately, not every function is differentiable, and more specifically, some functions are discrete. This means, they are defined on a discrete space.

I was very surprised I encountered so few questions about this topic on this site.

Suppose I have a function $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that maps every element $a \in A$ to a certain weight $r\in \mathbb{R}$ where $A$ is a finite set. How can I find the (relative) extrema of such a function?

I am familiar with the neighbour algorithm:

We somehow define a relation $\equiv$ on $A$ which we call the neighbour relation (how we define this relation depends on the problem) and then we take a random element $a \in A$. Suppose we are looking for a maximum. Then, we can check whether the neighbours have a larger weight. If there is not such an element, we have found a local maximum. If there is such an element, we repeat this on the neighbour with the largest weight. Eventually, we will find a local maximum.

Are there any other algorithms to find extrema that are useful? Can we extend these so we can find global minimums instead of relative ones?

Note that I'm not interested in brute force methods, as these are not useful in practice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the set or the function has some structure then you can try to take advantage of that in designing an algorithm. In full generality there's no choice but brute force.

Comment: If $A\subset \mathbb R$, and if $f=g|_A$ for some differentiable $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, you can sometimes work with $g$ instead.

Comment: A is finite, so the function can never be differentiable;